# Can I use a PC/104plus board on a PCI-104 connector

Tags: embedded, bus

The problem is: I have a miniPCI card that I need to attach to a motherboard that only has an PCI-104 connector available for expansion. So i found an adapter that is a [PC/104plus to MiniPCI adapter](http://www.lippertembedded.de/daten/downloads/General_Accessories/ds_S104P-MPCI.pdf). My questions are:

1. Is PC/104plus compatible with a PCI-104 connector? (I will not be attaching anything else to it). I read [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC/104) which is clear that you can put PC/104 on PC/104plus. It also says that all of PC/104 , PC/104plus and PCI-104 use PCI bus, but it is not clear if I can attach a PC/104plus to a PCI-connector.
2. And if the above is yes, does it matter that is is not on a standalone stack with its own SBC but just a connector on a motherboard of an embedded PC?

EDIT: As many pointed I misread about PC/104 and it is NOT working with PCI bus, so please ignore it. But it does not change my question because the connector is PCI-104 and the expansion card is PC/104plus which does work with PCI.

Comment: Can you please add a link to the adapter that you found?

Comment: yes: http://www.lippertembedded.de/en/productoverview/accessories/6-short-pc104-plus-adapter-for-3-mini-pci-cards.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say that all three standards use the PCI bus, but the wikipedia article states that PC/104 bus uses the ISA bus, PC/104-*Plus* supports both ISA *and* PCI and PCI/104 supports *only* PCI bus.

From the [PC104 website](http://www.pc104.org/pci_104_specs.php), the difference between PC/104-*Plus* and PCI/104 is that the AT & XT (ISA bus) connectors have been removed for increased board real-estate.

So the answer appears to be yes, they are compatible since the 4 X 30 PCI interface connectors are identical.

[Connect Tech](http://www.connecttech.com/sub/products/PCI_PC104PlusAdapter.asp), amongst others, make standard PCI adapters which support both PC/104-*Plus* and PCI/104 cards with the same interface socket.

Comment: Your second link is to a device that allows a PC104 or PC104 Plus card to be used in a PCI slot on a normal computer, not something that grafts PCI functionality on to a PC104 motherboard.

Comment: @AngryEE - Yes, the OP asked about compatibility between PC/104-Plus and PCI/104. I included this link as an example that this is the case. PC/104 is not inluded since it uses a separate pair of connectors which emulate the AT & XT connectors of the PC-ISA bus.

Comment: Ah, too many hard to read characters.  My eyes and brain are failing me.